# related to fluid mechanics and its velocity variation with respect to area of cross section of pipe through which it's flowing and height

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, potential-flow

if water is drawn from a tank by two pipes of the same diameter and at the same depth such that one pipe ends at some height and the other reaches the ground in which pipe we can collect the water more faster?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the efficiency, since we don't need to spend any energy to collect the water, so, I assume you want to compare the speed of water collection.

If the horizontal sections of the two pipes had the same length, the speed of collection from the short pipe would be greater, since extending the length of a pipe downward cannot speed it up beyond what is already provided by the gravity.

In addition, provided that the water is collected at the end of a pipe (not at the ground level), collecting from the short pipe will eliminate the initial delay it would take for the water to reach the ground.

If the horizontal section of the short pipe was substantially longer than the horizontal section of the long pipe, more data would be needed to answer this question definitively.